# Fiware orion invalid date format

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I have question regarding DateTime, can this be left empty for example

```
{ value: '',
  type: 'DateTime',
  metadata: {}
}
```

I am getting error when sending entity with this attribute that date is invalid format. This is clear as day why but what format i would have to use for empty value.

I failed to find this information on documentation but i could miss it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use an empty value for `DateTime` attributes in [NGSIv2 API](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/). You have to provide a properly formatted date in ISO8601 format.

If you need to introduce the "no date" semantics in your system the best approach is to remove the attribute (e.g. `DELETE /v2/entities/E/attrs/A` if I'm remembering correctly).